# Find ellipses in cell images

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, ellipse

I have images of tissue section from which I want to isolate all crypts, i.e. the big ellipses that you can see in this image (after binary thresholding) :

[image: tissue section]

Here they look like circles but in the general cases they form approximate ellipses.

I've tried to use canny, findContours or hough_ellipse in openCV but without success.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe https://scikit-image.org/

Comment: Do you think of a particular function in skimage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't spent too long polishing this answer, but it should get you started and then you can tidy it up. The basic idea is to convert your yellow colour to white and everything else to black:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import cv2
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import distance_transform_edt

# Load the image
im = cv2.imread('cells.png')

# Form binary image which is white where orginal is yellow and black everywhere else
B = np.zeros_like(im[...,0])
B = im == [38, 230, 253]
cv2.imwrite('tmp.png', (B*255).astype(np.uint8))
```

That gets you this:

[image]

Now, do a [distance transform](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.distance_transform_edt.html):

```
# Get distance transform
distance = distance_transform_edt(B)

# Normalise for contrast and save
cv2.normalize(distance, distance, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
cv2.imwrite('result.png', distance.astype(np.uint8))
```

[image]

So, basically, the brighter the point is in the result image, the further it is from cell walls and other stuff. You can then find the maxima in here and use them for further checking.

Comment: Sounds like a great idea, I could use the maxima to estimate the center and shape of the ellipses. Thanks I'm going to try it!

Comment: For the record, I used this `distance_transform` approach and used maxima to extend a border iteratively until I meet walls on most directions (with a threshold). That does the job honestly and is pretty efficient Thanks again!